# Is it possible to make a HTTP POST to a standard ASP.Net Web Form using XMLHttpRequest/FormData?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, post, xmlhttprequest

Let's suppose we have an ASP.Net Web Form, Page.aspx, in which we do the following:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

            // grab the standard ASP.Net form
            var form = document.forms['ctl01'];

            form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                sendData(form);
            });
        });

    function sendData(form) {

            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const fd = new FormData(form);

            xhr.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                document.open();
                document.write(event.target.response);
                document.close();
            });

            xhr.addEventListener("error", function (event) {
                alert('Error!');
            });

            xhr.open("POST", "Page.aspx");
            xhr.send(fd);
        }
</script>
```

The reason for this setup is I want to take advantage of the XMLHttpRequest progress event to erm, show some progress indication because the postback may include files that take some time to upload.

The load event handler works great. As a result of the POST I get the contents of Page.aspx again and replace my current document. So it seems that some kind of POST actually does happen BUT, there is one problem. In Page.Load(), the Request.Form and Request.Files collections are empty so I can't process the form/files.

I tried adding the following header but without much luck:

`xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`

Do you think it is possible to make a successful POST (with page receiving data) using XMLHttpRequest/FormData, or is there some fundamental limitation that prevents this from happening for ASP.Net pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well any ajax call simply can run some code behind, but since the web page IS STILL sitting on the client side in the browser, then things like controls and the page state are NOT available.

So you don’t want a post back, but now you asking for a post back? (I am confused). I mean, either you post back the whole page (standard event post back). Or you drop the controls and things in question into a update panel, and then ONLY that part of the page is posted back. I fail to see any advantage of trying to send “more” of the page in a ajax call when the WHOLE idea is to NOT send the page in the first place, right?

I mean, if you need some extra values in the ajax call, then you have to get/grab those bits and parts from the page, and include that information in your ajax call. (perhaps as a json string).

Without a post back, then viewstate and all of the controls are STILL just sitting on the users desktop in the browser. The code behind, and even the page class object + code ARE OUT OF scope at this point in time. Only upon a post-back does the WHOLE page travel up to server - code behind runs - you have use of full controls on the page, and THEN the whole page travels back down to the client side (and this quite much means that JavaScript code will have to re-start!!!

However, if you need a few parts and values in a page and don't want a full post-back? Then simply put those parts into a update panel. you can then in JavaScript for example do this:

```
 varMyAspNetButton = docuement.GetElementById("Button1");
 varMyAspNetButton.Click();
```

The above will save you world poverty and not have to wire up a bunch of js and web methods since the js code simply CLICKS on your button (that is inside the update panel). In this case, of course a whole page post back does NOT occur, but the page load and events do in fact fire - these so called "partial" page post backs means that the code behind is LIMITED to the information (controls) inside of that up-date panel.

However, as noted, if you do a post back, then the browser page NOW travels up to the server - and that quite much means any js code client side is toast and now can't run, since a whole NEW fresh copy of the web page is about to travel down to the client side again - and that re-starts your js code.

As noted, you can do a partial page post back with a update panel. And in js you can fire a "click" or in fact MOST events of asp.net controls on that page with js.

But, then again?
You don't want a full page post back, and you likely don't want all of the controls and the whole page to travel up to the server. But then again you wondering why you can't use or access controls on the page with ajax calls? Well as noted, the server side code behind is OUT of scope and OUT of context when you make ajax calls. The web page does NOT exist server side. We don't know if the user turned off their computer, or will never do anything in that client side browser and web page. The server at that point in time has lost ALL KNOWLEGE of that web page. So any ajax call does not have use of the controls on the page, and does not even have use of viewstate either.

This tends to mean that say when using say a ajax system to up-load files? Well, you can't store the status in the web page server side - since the page DOES NOT really exist at that point in time. So you can call some web methods, and about the ONLY way to keep some values in context is to use session(), since that does not need the web page, or the view state to function and work.

The major down side of session() of course is that if some user has two tabs open or even two different browsers open? Well, session() is SHARED between those pages - so while session() is great, it also shared between ALL copies of web pages for that given user - and thus you need to add code to separate out each session "set" of values, or simply hope that the user will not have two pages in operation for such file up-loads.

But to answer your question?
You can do and achieve partial page pushbacks by using a up-date panela And thus you can have timer code or js code client side to continue to run since a full page life-cycle does NOT occur. In other words, you control what part of the web page will and is sent up to the server side by using a update panel.

If you don't use a up-date panel, then any ajax calls you make WILL have to pass the data from the browser side, since it STILL just sitting on the users desktop, and any code behind can't grab, nor reach out, or see or even KNOW that the web page exists client side.

So you either pass extra values from the web page with your ajax calls OR YOU can use a update panel, drop controls inside and then the partial page post back will ONLY send up and have use of what you want inside of that panel. So you have two really great choices.

And in either case (a full page post back) or a partial one?
Grab a reference to the client side asp.net button, and fire off a .click event. You can I suppose wire up all kinds of _doPostBack in js, but with update panels and the click() trick, then you have a choice of how much of the page gets sent up, and it all quite much automatic wired up for you and saves a TRUCKLOAD of work that you would have to manually write and wire up if you don't use a update panel to control this.

So you get that "partial" page post back, and in that case the code and events inside of that up-date panel can update/see/use/modify controls in that up-date panel, but anything outside of that up-date panel will NOT have traveled up to the server.

And if you don't use a update-panel, then any ajax call is just that - a direct call to the server side - but the web page STAYS client side - thus on-load and any of the controls or objects or in fact the WHOLE class form object that represents that web page IS STILL SITTING client side - thus as noted, no on-load, no code behind can touch or even see or know about the values of controls on that page, and as noted there is also no ViewState either.

The WHOLE idea of ajax calls is that you did not want and never did want the page to travel up to the server, and then be re-rendered, and then re-sent back down to the client side. But you need to be 100% crystal clear here:

Without a page post back (or partial one with update panels), then the web page does NOT exist any more server side. Web pages are state-less and once the round trip has occurred (web page up to server - code behind runs, page sent back to client), then as far as the server is concerned (and you the developer) that web page is GONE and DOES NOT exist anymore at all - it is out of scope and from your point of view (and the server point of view) that web page does NOT exist anymore the instant it been sent back down to the client side. As noted, the only exception that is practical here is session() values - since they are not part of any given web page.

So, you have to decide if you want a partial page post back to get at and modify some values with server side code.

Or you pass the values with your ajax calls and the returned values can then update the browser controls. And of course once you do eventually do that say full page post back, then the code behind can certainly see + use any controls that the client js code changed - but can only do so with that full page post back, or as noted, controls limited to a update panel if we are talking about a partial page post back (update panel).

You either have to include additional data in your ajax calls, or consider using a partial page post back to send up part of the web page if you need to modify that part of the page with code behind. Or as noted, return information with your ajax call, and then update the client side. There not really a in-between choice here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying to do a full page postback, not partial. Perhaps I should have made it more explicit because XHR is used for partial postbacks. My POST target is Page.aspx, not some WebMethod within it for example... The only reason I am hijacking the submit event of the ASP.Net form is so that I can leverage the progress even of XHR to display some progress information during the full postback.

Comment: Perhaps spent too much time the narrative about page post back. The problem is if you post the full page back, then when that whole page comes back down to the client - then any js code you have is 100% re-loaded and re-starts. So I don't think you can really do a full page post back - since then any progress information would re-set - (now you could send down information that I suppose does update the progress - but that is a FULL page life cycle. Thus, i suspect you need or want to use some kind of update panel - since a full page life cycle going to re-set and re-start all and any js code.

Comment: Reset and restart of js code is in fact desirable, as I want the page to do the same next time (post itself through xhr when I submit it). I did in fact try to use an UpdatePanel which would provide just a "please-wait" functionality and not % progress indication, but FileUpload (input type="file") controls do not work within UpdatePanels. I have seen mentions of an asynchronous file upload control (in AjaxControlToolkit) that does work within an UpdatePanel, but alas it is nowhere to be found in recent versions of the .dll

Comment: By the way, progress indication is supposed to happen during the xhr postback through the progress event. When that finishes, Page.Load should fire up as per normal page lifecycle. Which it does, but with empty Request.Form and Request.File collections. So I am assuming there is something inherently wrong with the xhr postback of the asp.net form.